# HibernateCallback and getCurrentSession difference

Tags: hibernate, spring

Can I use geCurrentSession() instead of using HibernateCallback to get the session?. If both sessions are managed by Spring, why do I need a Callback ? Is there any performance advantage associated with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a well-configured Spring application, both are equivalent except in one case: when there is no current transaction context. In this case, getCurrentSession() won't work, whereas using a HibernateCallback will open a session and a Hibernate transaction for you and close them at the end.

Note that [the documentation of HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) mentions that getCurrentSession() should be preferred:

> NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can
>   also be coded in plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started
>   projects, consider adopting the standard Hibernate3 style of coding
>   data access objects instead, based on
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

It also says:

> Note that HibernateTemplate will perform its own Session management,
>   not participating in a custom Hibernate CurrentSessionContext unless
>   you explicitly switch "allowCreate" to "false".

Mixing both ways of doing is thus not a good idea.

My preference is to avoid HibernateTemplate, use the Hibernate Session API directly, and use Spring-managed declarative transactions.

Comment: @Nizet: Thanks for that. I think I'll go with Hibernate3 style .